# vulnerable java script library

Tags: wordpress, security

I created a website using wordpress, and I scanned the website for security issuess using Acunetix and found an issue which is vulnerable java script library and said to update javascript libary I don't know how, so my question how to update javascript library, os is windows using xampp version 5.6

Comment: is it the jquery library? they basically are trying to ensure backwards compatibility in IE and to support no longer updated plugins and themes.

Comment: I didn't understand you I still have the same problem and I do not know why I have this problem

Comment: Give a screenshot of the error.

Comment: this is what's written https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnEtIrO7xDITzxouCZ8yeC9Vwr_0 this the link for the error report, I Figure out the problem and it was plupload library and I tried to upgrade but I am not sure if I succeed or not hopefully someone will fix this problem